# Do Shulkers despawn in Minecraft 1.12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do Shulkers despawn if I get far away enough from them? I'm not asking if they despawn in peaceful mode because they don't. I'm asking if they despawn when I'm far enough away. I didn't find anything online so I thought I would give this question a try here.

Answer (score 4):

Shulkers don't despawn and don't respawn. They are generated alongside with The End City structures as they are generated as the city spawns, and remain there until killed. They may teleport around in certain conditions, but they remain "persistent" wherever they teleport to; if you move away and unload the chunks they were in, then return loading the chunk again, they are still there.

Answer (score -2):

They don't. Also in 1.17, they have a chance of spawning a new Shulker when it hits a different Shulker with its bullet.

Comment: You shouldn’t say “in 1.17” because nothing is confirmed, only snapshots

Comment: What do you base this on?

Comment: I suppose this answer's downvotes are no longer deserved since the shulker duplicating mechanic was added.